# jQuery ajax post: PHP get's no content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm hesitating to ask, but I haven't found any solution so far. I always thought, it could just be a silly mistake, but I can't find it.

I have a jQuery 2.1 ajax POST to my PHP server:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://my-server.com/post-example.php",
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({ foo: "bar" }),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("SUCCESS");
  },
});
```

Safari tells me in the console, that the request data is correct and was sent. When trying to access `foo` inside PHP, everything is empty:

```
var_dump($_POST); // array(0)
$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($foo); // string(0)
```

When I try to POST with curl, I get results in `php://input`:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"foot":"bar"}' http://www.my-server.de/post-example.php

// on PHP side
var_dump($_POST); // array(0)
$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($foo); // string(13) "{"foo":"bar"}"
```

I can't find a reason why. Maybe there is something wrong in my PHP configuration, but I already set the `always_populate_raw_post_data = On` in my `php.ini`.

I also tried without `contentType` and `dataType`, same effect.

Comment: not same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript

Comment: Unfortunately no. I can reach the server, and I get every output back, but the request vars from PHP are empty.

Comment: Hmm why stringify? You can just post with data: { foo: "bar" }, don't know if it will make a difference though.

Comment: I tried it without stringify, same result

Answer (score 1):

You are sending string and not JSON, fix it like this:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "res.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: { foo: "bar" },
     success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
     }
 });
```

`print_r($_POST)` returned this:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it without the `dataType` and with and without stringify. Unfortunately, I still get no results in PHP when looking at `file_get_contents("php://input")`. Any other idea?